# How do I access the current record from VBA within a continuous form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a continuous form and I simply want to access the current record from a VBA function that is invoked after I update. In this function, I referenced the objects separately so that I could put a watch on them and see what was there. *f* (the form) looks normal. The content of `Recordset` and `RecordsetClone` is shown as *"Object/Recordset2"* in the debugger. When the *rs* assignment executes, I get an exception that only states *"mismatched type"*. I've tried lots of different variations on this and nothing seems to work right. This should be simple and forthright, but ...

```
Private Sub Line_AfterUpdate()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim f As Form

    Set f = Me
    Set rs = f.RecordsetClone
    MsgBox rs.Fields("RawLine")
End Sub
```

I am using Access 2013, but earlier development on this DB was in Access 2007.

Comment: me.ControlName, or me!collum name will reference the current record, why bother with a recordset?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Doh! Thanks! There seems to be all sorts of stuff in Access that you can't find out about because of the nature of the docs. I do updates to other fields. A Me.Refresh is then needed to update the display with the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the revised code. Thanks to Albert D. Kallal for the information I needed.

```
Private Sub Line_AfterUpdate()
    Dim line As New TemplateLineClass

    Call SetFileRefresh(1)
    Call line.init(Nz(Me!RawLine, ""))
    Me!before = line.before
    Me!after = line.after
    Me!FieldMarker = line.subName
    Me!DefaultValue = line.DefaultValue
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Originally I was trying to access the current record via the Recordset or RecordsetClone fields. Apparently when you do this, you do not see the updated fields during the AfterUpdate event call. You DO see the updates when you use the Me!fieldName method.

Note that the AfterUpdate event is on the field, not the form.